# PHP/Javascript - Change 2nd Select element based on selection in first Select element and retain selections through POST & page reload

Tags: javascript, php, html, select, onchange

First SELECT:

```
<?php

function select_size($itemSizes){

echo "<select id=\"size\" name=\"size\">";

    $sizes = array("0" => "All Sizes","1" => "Large","2" => "Medium","3" => "Small");

    foreach($sizes as $s => $si){
        if($itemSizes == $s){$selected = "selected";}
        echo "<option value=\"" . $s . "\" $selected>" . $si . "</option>\n";
        $selected = "";
    }

echo "</select>\n";

}

?>
```

Second SELECT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#eventCategory").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#eventType").html(options[val]);
    });

    var options = ["
        <option value='all_items'>ALL Items</option>
        <option value='red'>red</option>
        <option value='blue'>blue</option>
        <option value='green'>green</option>
    ];

});
```

First select retains value due to PHP. `onChange` is working properly as once a value in Select #1 is chosen, Select #2 populates with it's appropriate list. The problem I'm having is Select #2 is not retaining it's value through a POST and page reload. I've worked out a bit of JS that does this but it fouls up the `onChange` function. I'm trying to achieve both at the same time and have failed thus far. Yes, I'm an amateur with JS. Pretty good with many other languages. The syntax is causing me troubles. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: _“The problem I'm having is Select #2 is not retaining it's value through a POST and page reload.”_ - so where is the server-side code that creates it then? You have just shown us some JavaScript that manipulates the already existing field.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an ajax when first select triggers `onChange` event.
Then, on the success of this Ajax, you can get values from php and changing the second one. As you are using ajax, the first option will not be modified.

As you asked for "reloading page" you will need to print a script in the view that browsers can render, this can look like:

if you can know the ID of each option (if any):

```
echo "<script> $('#selector1 option#'.$idOption.').attr('selected', 'selected'); </script>";
```

if you can't know the ID of each or there are any id to catch, you'll get the value for sure, the script will look like:

```
$('#selector1 option[value="'.$value.'"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

where in the first case $idOption is the id of the option selected on first selector and retrieved from php. $value in the second script is.. well, the value.

don't really know if there solves your entire problem as i can only see a part of your code, i'll edit it if you provide feedback.

Maybe you would var_dump / console.log values for getting a backtrace of your data and see where it's lost to ensure you pass the needed data around your functionallity.